# image_tag not working for external URL, returns object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Unfortunately the below is not working for me @shps is a list of urls.

```
<h1>Shewps</h1>
<% @shps.each do |shp| %>
<%= image_tag(shp) %>
<% end %>
```

The HTML I get is as follows:

`<img alt="#&lt;shp:0xa0c5af8&gt;" src="/assets/#&lt;Shp:0xa0c5af8&gt;">`

It seems shp is returning an object?, when i use shp outside of the image tag it returns as a string. Also it is looking in ./assets/ when it is an external url.

Comment: Does your `Shps` model represent a database containing a column with the URL? For example, maybe it should be `<%= image_tag shp.url %>`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `ActiveRecord` object, you should pass actual url to `image_tag` method. So, assuming you store it in `url` column:

```
<% @shps.each do |shp| %>
  <%= image_tag shp.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to call shp.url , url being one of the attributes for my model. shp returns the entire object.